# Removing unit from heterogeneous collection

Tags: haskell

Recently I've been working on a project that uses several different monad transformers. I got tired of writing functions for running my various monad stacks, so I decided to write a generic function for executing them. It goes something like this:

```
class MonadRun outer args inner | outer -> args, args outer -> inner where
    monadRun :: outer -> args -> inner

-- Base instances: The Identity monad can be removed, while other monads, in general, cannot
instance MonadRun (Identity a) () a where
    monadRun a _ = runIdentity a

instance (Monad m, ma ~ (m a), ma' ~ (m a), u ~ ()) => MonadRun ma u ma' where
    monadRun a _ = a
```

Then I have instances for each of the monad transformers:

```
instance (MonadRun (m a) r' m') => MonadRun (ReaderT r m a) (r, r') m' where
    monadRun outer (r, r') = monadRun (runReaderT outer r) r'
```

The other instances are just boilerplate, same as the `ReaderT` instance. If I have a monad such as

```
> type Test = StateT Int (ReaderT Bool IO)
>:t monadRun (undefined :: Test ())
monadRun (undefined :: Test ()) :: (Int, (Bool, ())) -> IO ((), Int)
```

The type of the resulting function has a redundant `()`; it should be reduced to `(Int, Bool) -> IO ((), Int)` (the `()` in the return type should be removed as well if possible; but that isn't as important to me.) I can redefine the instance as follows:

```
instance (MonadRun (m a) r' m', r'' ~ (r, r')) => MonadRun (ReaderT r m a) r'' m' where
    monadRun outer (r, r') = monadRun (runReaderT outer r) r'

instance (MonadRun (m a) () m') => MonadRun (ReaderT r m a) r m' where
    monadRun outer r = monadRun (runReaderT outer r) ()
```

and I will get the correct type. Now the questions:

1 . Has someone written something like this already (running arbitrary monad stacks)? If so, I can abandon my efforts.

2 . Can this be written so that units are 'automatically' eliminated from the resulting type? In the given example, the `()` occurs at the end. But that wouldn't always be the case, `()` can occur anywhere in the stack. I tried doing something like this, but couldn't get it to work.

```
class Tuple a b c | a b -> c where fst' :: c -> a; snd' :: c -> b;
instance Tuple a () a ....
instance Tuple () a a ....
instance Tuple a b (a,b) ....
```

3 . Instead of some complex nested tuple type, is there a different (better) heterogeneous collection I can use?

[For those interested, here is the complete code.](http://lpaste.net/2660118940016967680)

Comment: http://lpaste.net will format/highlight Haskell properly.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got this 'working'. First of all I created a heterogenous collection using `DataKinds`:

```
infixr 7 :>
data Args (xs :: [*]) where
    None :: Args '[]
    (:>) :: x -> Args xs -> Args (x ': xs) 

type family Concat (a :: [*]) (b :: [*]) :: [*]
type instance Concat '[] ys = ys
type instance Concat (x ': xs) ys = x ': (Concat xs ys)

concatArgs :: Args xs -> Args ys -> Args (Concat xs ys)
concatArgs None x = x
concatArgs (x :> xs) ys = x :> concatArgs xs ys
```

Then a class for running a single level of a monad:

```
class Rule tyCons m input fr res | tyCons -> m input fr res where
    rule :: tyCons m fr -> Args input -> m (Args res)

instance Monad m => Rule (ReaderT r) m '[r] a '[a] where 
    rule m (r :> None) = liftM (:> None) $ runReaderT m r
    rule _ _ = undefined

instance Monad m => Rule (WS.WriterT w) m '[] a '[a, w] where
    rule m _ = liftM (\(x,y) -> x:>y:>None) $ WS.runWriterT m
```

Then one for sequencing rules:

```
class RunRules input args output | input -> args, args input -> output where
    runRules :: input -> Args args -> output

-- base case
instance (Monad m, ma ~ (m a), u ~ '[], mar ~ (m (Args ar)),
          RemU a ar  -- if a == () then '[] else '[a]
         ) => RunRules ma u mar where
    runRules a _ = liftM remU a

-- recursive case
instance 
    ( Rule tyCon0 m0 arg0 fr0 out0, RunRules (m0 (Args out0)) arg1 (m1 f), UnpackArgs f f'
    , args ~ Concat arg0 arg1, From arg0 args arg0 arg1
    , Monad m1
    ) => RunRules (tyCon0 m0 fr0) args (m1 f')  where
        runRules input args = liftM unpackArgs $ runRules (rule input arg0) arg1
          where (arg0, arg1) = from (Proxy :: Proxy arg0) args
```